# How to remove mouse listener after click on button?

Tags: java, swing, button, netbeans

this is very specific. So I am making small quiz app and everything is done but I have problem. So when I click on correct answer it goes green and correctAnswer counter goes up. If I click wrong answer it will go red and correct answer will be green. And I have next button for next question.

So you already see where is problem? When I click on answer I still can click on other answers. I don't want to disable buttons after click because I want them to became green/red.

I want to be able only click on next button when I pick answer. But I don't want to disable answers buttons because they will lose colour.

Here is some of my methods

```
   private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        jButton1.setBackground(Color.green);
        Kviz.correctAnswers++;
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        jButton1.setBackground(Color.green);
        jButton2.setBackground(Color.red);
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }
```

Comment: Well, depending on what you're doing, you could wait till the presses something like an accept button before telling them if it's correct or not; you could disable the other options once one ins selected, but that does preclude the possibility for the user to change their mind

Answer (score 0):

Just make a variable called `answerPicked`. Set it to false, and then any time a user picks an answer, set it to true. Use it to stop the action listener from doing anything if an answer was already picked. Then, when the user moves to the next question, you can reset `answerPicked` to false, so the user can pick an answer again.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create an boolean instance variable which controls whether user clicked or not.

```
boolean bIsClicked = false;

   private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        if(bIsClicked == false){
           jButton1.setBackground(Color.green);
           Kviz.correctAnswers++;

           //change the status
           bIsClicked = true;
        }
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
         if(bIsClicked == false){        
             jButton1.setBackground(Color.green);
             jButton2.setBackground(Color.red);
            // TODO add your handling code here:

            //change the status
            bIsClicked = true; 
           }
    }
```